# Extjs4.2 - getView() methods are not working in controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a simple Extjs4.2 MVC application. I have created a view and linked that view to apps controller using refs. In refs I have tried using alias/itemId of that view. Here is the refs:

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'answersCont',
    selector: 'question' //-- alias of view
}],
```

But I am not getting view constructor when using `this.getAnswersCont()`.
Can anyone please help me identifying what is the missing link here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `question` view is **not rendered** in the DOM. So you need to use `autoCreate:true` in your `ref` which will first run the `ComponentQuery` to see if a Component matching that selector exists on the page. If not, it will **automatically create** one using the xtype provided.

Like this:

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'answersCont',
    autoCreate:true,
    selector: 'question' //-- alias of view
}],
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for the reply. But I have tried `autoCreate: true` already. The problem is by doing that I'm not able to get access to its store and some user defined methods. I think autoCreate returns constructor object where my store and methods are not attached. I suspect this must be because I set store after callParent call in view. Is this True?

Comment: yes,its seems true,But can confirm only after looking at your code or you can try it